# Mac Python Close Window

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, automation, window

I was wondering if there was a way of watching for a window to open and when it does close it? I've got a very annoying VPN client on our Mac systems that is very verbose and gets really annoying. There's no configuration to change this, so I'm wondering if I could write a Python script that is always running and watching for the window to open and close it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no global notification that gets generated every time a window is opened, and no standard notification that every app uses, and no other way to do this in general, short of (a) injecting code into the VPN client, (b) using deprecated functionality like `CGRemoteOperation`, or (c) reverse engineering undocumented Window Server functionality.

So, the simplest solution is to periodically poll for windows and close them, probably using UI scripting via ScriptingBridge, NSAppleScript (through pyobjc), or appscript.

For example:

```
se = appscript.app('SystemEvents')
while True:
    try:
        client = se.application_processes['Annoying VPN Client']
        window = client.windows['Annoying Window']
        close = window.buttons[1]
        close.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you're interested in the other options—which you won't be able to do from Python—let me know. If you're familiar with system-level C and ObjC programming, creating a SIMBL program that hooks into the ObjC runtime to insert your own delegate in front of the existing one and intercept the relevant messages isn't that hard.

Comment: This sounded like an interesting problem - the cocoa solution involves NSAppleEventManager, which is not supported by pyobjc - FWIW https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239